# Extending the domain of a multi-valued function to make it single-valued

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Suppose $f: I \rightarrow O$ is a partial but single-valued function. Then there are, in general use, three ways to make this function well behaved:

- Extending $O$ by defining $f(x)$ for all $x \in I$ that have no output, and then going over the extension to make sure nothing (that you care about) broke. This is interesting, but difficult, and is where we get things like like negatives, fractions, square roots and complex numbers.
- Restricting $I$ by deleting all $x \in I$ that have no outputs in $O$, and then going over the restriction to make sure nothing (that you care about) broke. This is quick and easy, but boring, and leads to things like "imaginary numbers aren't real".
- Ignoring the issue entirely and redefining "well behaved" to include partial functions. This is also quick and easy, and is usually used when properly restricting $I$ isn't actually that easy.

Now suppose $g:I \rightarrow O$ is a multi-valued but total function. Then there are, in general use, two ways to make this function well behaved:

- Restricting $O$ by deleting all "extra" outputs $g(x) \in O$, and then going over the restriction to make sure nothing (that you care about) broke. This is where we get things like the "principal" square root or the "principal" argument of the logarithm.
- Ignoring the issue entirely and redefining "well behaved" to include multi-valued functions. This is where the "plus-or-minus" sign in the quadratic formula (among others) comes from, and is usually employed when all $g(x)$'s potentially have meaning.

My question: **Has anyone ever tried to make $g$ well-defined by extending $I$, and if so, what happened?**

An idea to make it work: "tagging" each input $x \in I$ that has multiple outputs $g(x) \in O$ so each "tagged" $x$ has exactly one $g(x)$.

A trivial example: Let $g: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the "inverse" of the absolute value function on $\mathbb{R}$; that is, let $g(x) = \pm x$. Tagging $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ with $+$ and $-$ so $g(+x) = +x$ and $g(-x) = -x$ just gives us the identity function $\iota (x) = x$ as $\mathbb{R}^+$ is extended into $\mathbb{R}$.

A not-so-trivial example: Let $g(x): \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the "inverse" of the squaring function; that is, let $g(x) = \pm \sqrt{x}$. Tagging $x$ with, say $@$ and $\#$ so that $g(@x) = + \sqrt{x}$ and $g(\#x) = - \sqrt{x}$ is a fairly interesting function at first glance. Other inverse algebraic functions might get similar tagging systems.

I'm going to post this question now, work on the algebra to see what happens and then report my results. In the meantime, feel free to point me to people who have already done this (or something similar), or even do it yourself.

Comment: In my experience, a much more common solution is to extend the _codomain_ $O$, and view $f$ as a single valued function with codomain $2^O$. This is standard when trying to convert relations into functions, for example.

Comment: One potential issue I see with your technique is that it breaks the regular field operations. For instance, how do we define $#x + @y$? I suspect that, no matter how you do it, you will break associativity, etc.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Comment 1: So making it a set valued function where the set is composed of the multiple values of the original function? That falls under "ignoring the issue entirely" in my mind. Maybe not in practice, but certainly in spirit. Comment 2: I had noticed that it was difficult to define addition properly, in part because the freshman's dream isn't true for square roots. I'm still working on it, but you're probably right.